# Workfunction and Bond Energy

Tags: electrons, covalent-compounds

Workfunction is the minimum energy required to remove an electron from the surface of the material. If the striking photons does not have the required energy then it won't be able to eject the electron even though many photons can be striking the surface i.e. many low energy photons cannot be combined to get the required energy. In contrast to this many particles can combine to break a bond. Silicon for example has bond energy of 1.1eV, with an average energy of 0.026eV 42 (1.1/0.062) particles would be required to break the bond and set the electron free. Why is it that a similar thing not happen with photons?. If many photons strike the the surface than all their energy should add up and remove the electron

**EDIT**
I am watching lectures on Youtube on Chemistry and Semiconductor devices. In [this lecture at 4:45](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/chemistry/5-111-principles-of-chemical-science-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-4/) the instructor talks about workfunction. And in [this lecture at 42:00](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Lm__i7a-lM&index=5&list=PLF178600D851B098F) the instructor talks about the number of particles required to break a bond

Comment: By "many particles combine to break a bond" are you referring to chemical ionization? Also, what are the sources for the silicon bond energies and the "42 particles"?

Comment: Photons behave as 'particles' in this type of experiment. What is the experimental evidence that shows that ' many particles', presumably not photons, break the bond?

Comment: @zer0c00l If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’.

Comment: @quantum-americcino, I have added the sources in my original post. I tried searching more on this and it seems like many photons with low energy cannot combine to add up their energy, because is no mechanism for the absorption of light ([ASU](http://www.asu.edu/courses/phs208/phs208_iv/patternsbb/PiN/info/rdg/silicon/index.htm)) but many electrons can combine.